# How to encypt a zipoutputstream in Google dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, zip, google-cloud-dataflow, pgp

I need to **zip** and **encrypt** files in `Cloud Dataflow` with `Java`, using `ZipOutputStream` to upload them to `Google Cloud Storage`.

However I don't know how to encrypt it.

Can anyone help me with that. Following are the steps I am trying to do:

1) Read an already encrypted file 
2) Read the data
3) Perform decryption
4) Zip the file stream
5) Perform the encryption

Comment: Is your problem only in the last step? Can you explain a little bit more your pipeline?

Comment: How are the files encrypted and where are the encryption keys stored?

Comment: it will be useful to elaborate on the usecase a bit more and also share what you tries for better assistance.